# Distributing power evenly to multiple pins

Tags: arduino-uno

It's an arduino board, model UNO R3. I have 3 5cmx10cm heating pad power required 5V DC up to 1A and can withstand up to 12V DC. These 3 heating pad are wired up onto arduino board with red wires connected to pin 8 pin 9 and pin 10 on the digital side of the arduino and the black wire connected to GND (ground). Lastly I have a toggle on and off switch connected to the arduino with the red wire attached to digital pin 2 and the black wire to 5V. The arduino uno R3 withstand 20voltage and the 5V heating pads can withstand 12V. I would like my 20V external power to heat up all 3 heating pads evenly, how can I do this? Is it possible? Thank you!

Comment: You could put the three pads in series, so they run on 15-36 Volt. But I suspect there's more wrong here. You can't connect a 1A heating pad to an Arduino pin directly, as it can't deliver that much current, and will likely get damaged. The on-off switch also needs a (pull-down) resistor to work reliably.

Comment: Do not connect these heating pads to your Arduino. You will overload the Arduino. Also don't connect AC power to the Arduino.

Comment: To be clear, you should not try to draw power from Arduino pins. An arduino is made to output very low power control signals out of it's pins, NOT power. (You should draw at most 20 milliamps from each pin on the Arduino. That's 20 thousandths of an amp.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course it is possible.  But if all you need to do it to turn these heat pads on and off, an Arduino is perhaps not the most suitable technology.

But presuming these heat pads are a component of some more complex system that responds to other inputs or outputs to/from the Arduino, you will need a few more components.  You need to accomplish two things that the UNO R3 cannot accomplish by itself, because your heat pads are very much too large a load for your UNO to power directly.  (The power for a single LED bulb is about the most that you can draw from an output pin.)

1. You need to reduce your 20-V external power source down to something less than 12 volts to supply your heating pads.
2. You need to switch on and off up to 1 amp of current to flow to each of the three heating pads.  The UNO cannot do this directly.

There are a lot of ways to reduce your 20-volt supply down to less than 12 volts.  Some are much more efficient than others.  Probably the lowest cost efficient way is to use your 20-V source as the input a small DC to DC voltage down stepping converter.  These are available online from Chinese vendors for very low cost.  Just search for "DC-DC converter down".  A quick search finds one rated at 20 amps, with adjustable voltage output can be purchased for less than $10.  These are pretty efficient devices that don't waste the power that a simple voltage dropping resistor would waste.

Then you need either one or three 5-volt relays of some type to switch the power on to the heat pads.  The UNO pins output of 5-volts would not provide current to heat pads, put only enough current to energize the relay(s).  The relay(s) can be either solid state, or coil energized.  Just be sure the relay "contacts" are rated to handle well more than 1 amp if there are three of them, and more than 3-amps if only one.   An Arduino relay shield with four relays, each rated for 10 amps, can be purchased for less than $5.

If you only every want all three heat pads energized at the same time, you only need one relay, and one Arduino output to energize it.

The very simplest solution, if you only want all the pads heating simultaneously, would be to wire the three heat pads in series.  Then you could apply your 20-volts directly across all three heat pads, and you would not need any device to reduce your supply voltage.  Each heat pad would have 1/3 of 20 volts across it, which is well under their 12 volt tolerance.  And you would only need one relay.

Comment: Yes, I want to do exactly what you wrote in the last paragraph on my arduino uno r3 so I can connect 20volt (to power jack). When you say wire the three heating pads in a series. How does that look, am I to connect/attach all 3 red wires of heating together to each other?

Heating pads: https://www.adafruit.com/product/1481

Arduino: https://store.arduino.cc/usa/arduino-uno-rev3

Transistor: https://www.creatroninc.com/product/tip120-npn-darlington-power-transistor-60v-5a/?search_query=TIP1

Comment: Is a TIP120 - NPN Darlignton power transistor: the current flow between the collector and the emitter of is controlled by the current flow through the base The same thing as a DC-DC voltage down stepping converter?

Comment: Rebecca, I don't mean to be dismissive, you need to do some study on the difference between wiring components in series compared to wiring them in parallel.  If you are building this thing, you need to understand the wiring if something fails.  Just google "series vs parallel wiring".  I cannot explain without drawings, but it is like hoses connected end to end to make one long hose.  Those heat pads have no polarity, no "plus" and no "minus" so the color of the wire probably makes no difference.

Comment: https://www.creatroninc.com/product/tip120-npn-darlington-power-transistor-60v-5a/?search_query=TIP120&results=3

Comment: The transistor is not the same as a DC-DC converter.  You don't need this transistor.  It is not suitable technology for your application.  Perhaps someone told you to make a power switch out of it . . . Just get a relay.

Comment: The 5x10cm 5V operating heating pad (hand size) are already wired parallel and placed inside a chair. So I cannot re-wire and will have to get a DC-DC step down converter and relay to distribute heat to each of my 3 heating pads.

Comment: Rebecca . . why are you trying to use Arduino?  If all you want it to turn all 3 pads on and off at same time, just wire the 20-volt source, the switch, and all 3 pads in series, and disregard all else.  Google "series switch circuits" to understand this simple wiring.

Comment: Since heat pads are now wired in parallel, all additional that you need is the DC-DC converter.  The heat pads would be in parallel with each other, and in series with (or "connected to") the output of the DC-DC converter.  You would wire the switch in series with the 20-volt supply and the input side of the DC-DC converter . . .    You don't use Arduino, or relays, or transistor..

Comment: Or if the 20-volt supply has a built-in ON/OFF switch, you don't need to add another switch.  Just wire the input side of the DC-DC converter to the 20-volt supply.  Then just turn on the 20-volt supply when you want heat.  Adjust the output of the DC-DC converter to something between 5 volts and 12 volts.  A higher voltage (like full 12 volts) will make more heat, but the heat pads might burn out quickly, especially if they are surrounded by fabric that limits heat conduction away from the pads.

Comment: Rebecca . . . on more thing . . . you need to be sure whether your 20-volt source puts out AC voltage, or DC voltage.   If it is AC, then then you need to buy a step-down converter that will work with either AC or DC as input.  They are about the same price.  As you may know, the heat pads are designed to be power by DC voltage.   I'm sorry to all that this is so far off Arduino topic, but why not try to help?.

Comment: Yes its AC 20V adapter, but does the DC-DC converter have a power jack to plug in the adapter?

Comment: If your 20V supply is AC then you can use a 1:2 step-down transformer to drop the voltage to 10V. That's cheap and easy. You can't use AC to power an Arduino, nor can you run your heater from the Arduino. As others have said, it sounds like an Arduino doesn't have any place in this project. You just need switch and a way to lower your 20V to something in the 5V to 12V range, and since it's AC a step-down transformer would be perfect.

Comment: It contains everything needed to support the microcontroller; simply connect it to a computer with a USB cable or power it with a AC-to-DC adapter or battery to get started.https://store.arduino.cc/usa/arduino-uno-rev3                                                              
                                                                              the arduino is serving as an outlet to plug in my 20V AC Adapter. How else would I attach?

Comment: John P. My 20volt AC Adapter won't be able to attach the DC-DC converter because the end of the adapter is not a wire it's a plug, what other options are there?

Comment: Buy one of these from this or another vendor.     https://www.ebay.com/itm/3ft-DC-Power-Socket-to-Bare-Wire-5-5x2-1mm-DC-Female-to-Open-End-18AWG/161822453332?hash=item25ad5eae54:g:EDEAAOSwiLdV8kCn:rk:9:pf:0

Comment: Duncan C the arduino can withstand up 20V and my 3 heating pads are 15V all together. It's not a heater it's a heating pad and the electronic store and the teacher never said that the heating pad aren't allowed or else I would of created a different project.

Comment: Rebecca, if this is an Arduino class project, I take back what I said about the Arduino not being appropriate.  Many learning projects are not exactly appropriate Arduino technology, but we still can learn from them.  But you will just be using it as a switch, and you need to go back to using the Arduino to energize a relay that will turn on/off power to the pads.  I hope the teacher can help confirm your wiring.

Comment: So I need to get a relay and also the DC-DC conveter, that's the rest that I need?

Comment: You need to get an AC to DC converter.  Previously I did not understand that your 20 volts is AC.  And a relay shield like this.  https://www.ebay.com/itm/One-1-Channel-Relay-Module-Shield-5V-Control-250V-10A-w-Optocoupler-for-Arduino/121936150139?epid=1275973984&hash=item1c63f5fe7b:g:SYMAAOSw3RZaN-5D:rk:22:pf:0   . . . And the adapter plug.

Comment: Or more simple to discard the 20-volt power and buy a different power that is already 5 volts like this which is not expensive:    https://www.ebay.com/itm/5V-1A-2A-3-4A-5A-DC-Power-Supply-Charger-Adapter-ID-OD-2-5mm-x-5-5mm-Center-PSU/351139392368?hash=item51c189eb70:m:m8cFepWThEUsYT1wGkrQ5Eg:rk:9:pf:0   You can cut the end off with the connector and connect wires to the relay contacts.  This is a different size plug than Arduino

Comment: 5V barely heats up the one pad even though its it's a 5V heating  pad, it just feels warmish. With 5V the 3 heating pad connected to the arduino dont even get any heat because the arduino is also using power to be on. I think I'll use the ac adapter and buy a DC-DC converter.

Comment: It is necessary that the DC-DC converter and the AC/DC adapter have to be seperate from my arduino or can I have it connected to the arduino? On the arduino website it says the limit of input voltage of arduino is 20voltage

Comment: Looking at UNO datasheet, it shows that the UNO can be powered from the same 20 volts AC source, but the power for the heat pads cannot go THROUGH the UNO.  The UNO R3 and the AC-DC converter must be connected to the 20-volt supply in parallel.  Connecting your UNO to the 20-volt supply might tax the UNO R3 voltage regulator heavily and it might run hot, and might fail early for that.  It will work, but probably is not the best wayy

Comment: Okay, so I will keep the two seperate.

Comment: To use one power source, it might be better to power the UNO from the output of the AC to DC converter at the lower voltage of the heat pads.  The UNO will accept 20 volts, but that might be a lot for the built in voltage regulator to handle.  It may be okay either way.  It depends on the quality of the voltage regulator, and the safety factor in the 20 volt rating of the UNO.

Comment: Rebecca . . . I don't mean to discourage you, but those heat pads are very small in heat output if you really want to feel any warmth from them on a chair cushion, or back.  They only put out 5 watts each at 5 volts,  And perhaps 12 to 15 watts of heat output when supplied with 12 volts DC.  That isn't a lot. You should be prepared to possibly not feel much heat.  You are designing serial number one of this device, and sometimes the first version isn't quite optimum.

Comment: Rebecca . . .I look for an AC-DC step down converter to link here, but I can only find for sale from China, which means a month or more to arrive.  If you need sooner, you can eliminate the 20-volt supply all together, and use this instead with 120 volts AC input, but with fixed 12 volts DC output for heat pads.   https://www.ebay.com/itm/12V-5A-60W-DC-Power-Supply-Switching-Adapter-Transformer-For-5050-LED-Strip-CCTV/253783039111?hash=item3b16a5dc87:g:T4kAAOSwEetV8jJL:rk:28:pf:0

Comment: I also have a 120volts AC input with fixed 12volts AC output. Should I use that instead of the 20volts AC input? Will it heat up the 3 heating pad?

Comment: Perhaps it would work, but the heat pad manufacturer says to apply DC voltage only, so there might be some problem with it over time.  And with "seats" on the line, you probably don't want to take a chance.

Comment: I got 120V AC input to 12V DC output that can work. Do I still need a relay and step down converter? Will the arduino be using some of that power to power it self?

Comment: Yes, a 120VAC to 12VDC power supply that provides enough current for all 3 heating pads and the Arduino would work to power everything. Add up the current requirements of all 3 heating pads and the arduino (although the current used by the Arduino will be very small) . Yes, you will still need a relay module so that the Arduino can turn the power to the heating pads on and off.

Answer (score 0):

Can you state the full goal of the project? Are you supposed to be turning the heating pad on and off with the Arduino? (The rest of my answer assumes that that is what you want to do.)

You will need a source of DC power to drive the Arduino. (You can't power an Arduino with AC.)

You will need a 5V relay so you can turn off the power to the heating pad from a logic pin on the Arduino. There are various relay modules made to be controlled by microcontrollers like Arduinos. This one, for example: https://www.jameco.com/z/VMA406-Velleman-Arduino-Compatible-5V-Relay-Module_2255306.html?CID=GOOG&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIr9bSioLT4AIVkpOzCh3X7gqbEAQYBSABEgLf1PD_BwE

Then you will be able to rig the Arduino to turn the relay on and off. You'll wire the power for the heating pad through the relay. You will also need a way to lower the voltage of your power supply to the 5V - 12V range you mentioned. A 1:2 step-down transformer would be a good choice for that.

Comment: I can power arduino with an AC-DC which I have. I got 120V AC input to 12V DC output that can work. Do I still need a relay and step down transformer? Will the arduino be using some of that power to power it self?

Comment: You still have not explained what you are trying to do very clearly, so it's really hard to answer your questions.

Comment: YES YOU NEED A RELAY, assuming your goal is to control the heating pad from the Arduino. An Arduino cannot drive high power devices like heaters. You need to set up the relay as a switch. A digital line from the Arduino will turn the relay on and off.  The relay will switch power to your heating pad on and off.

Comment: Note that feeding 12V into the Arduino's barrel connector will put a lot of strain on it's voltage regulator. A linear voltage regulator like the one in the Arduino takes excess voltage and converts it to heat. So the Arduino's power supply will have to "burn off" 12-5, or 7 volts as heat. The voltage regulator will get quite hot.